# How to rewrite token stream more than once using ANTLR4

Tags: antlr, token, antlr4

I implement simple preprocessor using the great ANTLR4 library. The program itself runs in several iterations - in each iteration the future output is modified slightly.

Currently I use [TokenStreamRewriter](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/TokenStreamRewriter.html) and its methods `delete`, `insertAfter`, `replace` and `getText`.

Unfortunately I can't manage to rewrite tokens that was rewritten before (got `IllegalArgumentException`). This [is not a bug](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/TokenStreamRewriter.java#L528) but according to the [source code](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/TokenStreamRewriter.java) multiple replacement can't be achieved in any way.

I suppose that a proper solution exists as this appears to be a common problem. Could anyone please hint me? I'd rather use some existing and tested solution than reimplement the rewriter itself.

Maybe the rewriter isn't the right tool to use.

Thanks for help

Comment: Does pull request [#505](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/pull/505) meet your needs?

Comment: I must admit that I don't understand why ANTLR, a very good parsing engine that can build trees, suggests that rewriting the token stream is a good idea.   Why not rewrite the trees? The trees are at least persistent, and after you change them, you still have the whole tree, so you can arguably do it again and in fact as many times as you like.    Even if one sticks to rewriting the token stream, why it is that you cannot rewrite more than once (maybe because it is a stream and the tokens have gone by; maybe it should be a token array?).

Comment: it's interesting but according to issue tracker next version may bring this feature... Anyway, I read the source of TokenStreamRewriter and it actually provides rewriting of rewritten code when it is all included in new relacement and I can live with that

Comment: @IraBaxter: In some cases it's necessary to rewrite the token stream, e.g. macro replacement, since without replacing the tokens it's not possible to even construct the parse tree. Although the option to manipulate the trees would be a great addition.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I am using because I need to make a replacement in the token and the `Tokenrewriter` does not make the job correctly when you have multiple replacements in one context.

In each context I can make the stream of tokens visible and I use an array to copy all the tokens in the context and create a string with the replacement and after that, I use `Rewriter->replace( ctx->start , ctx->stop , tokentext ) ;`

Some code here  for a context:

```
string TAB[265];
string tokentext = "";
for (int i = ctx->start->getTokenIndex(); i <= ctx->stop->getTokenIndex(); i++)
{
TAB[i] = TOK->get(i)->getText();
// if (TOK->get(i)->getText() != "As" && TOK->get(i)->getText() != "Private" && TOK->get(i)->getText() != "Public")
//if (TOK->get(i)->getText() == "=")
//{
if (TAB[i] == "=") { TAB[i] = ":="; }
// if (TAB[i] == "=") { TAB[i] = "="; }      // autres changements

if (TAB[i] != "As" && TAB[i] != "Private" && TAB[i] != "Public") { tokentext += TAB[i]; }
cout << "nombre de tokens du contexte" << endl;
cout << i << endl;
}
tokentext = tokentext + " ;";
cout << tokentext << endl;
        
Rewriter->replace(ctx->start, ctx->stop, tokentext);
```

It's a a basic code I use to make the job robust. Hope this will be useful.

Comment: My answer is very clear and  the question of  Lucas Trzesniewski was in 2014 we are in 2022  and normally i don't have to answer but i have the problem in my project. i find a work around waiting for a good rewrite of the rewriter  or information .

Comment: I made some tweaks on the text surrounding the piece of code, if you feel that I changed the original intent, feel free to revert it.

Comment: No problem it's ok. the dynamic solution is better because you allocate the memory with the minimum.  I encounter exactly  the problem described and the only robust command was  Rewriter->replace(ctx->star, ctx->stop,  chaine ). la chaine est la chaine Pascal obtenue qui remplace la chaine VB6

Answer (score 0):

Good evening
Now a dynamic code for the same problem. First you must have made visible in your listener class the Token stream and the rewriter
Here is the code of the constructor of my VB6Mylistener class

```
class VB6MYListener : public VB6ParserListener {
public:         string FicName;
                int numero ;          // numero de la regle 
                wstring BaseFile;
                CommonTokenStream* TOK ; 
                TokenStreamRewriter* Rewriter ;

// Fonctions pour la traduction avec le listener   void functions 
created by ANTLR4  ( contextes  )

VB6MYListener( CommonTokenStream* tok , wstring baseFile, TokenStreamRewriter* rewriter , string Name)
            {
        TOK = tok;                  // Flux de tokens
        BaseFile = baseFile;        // Fichier entree  en VB6   
        Rewriter = rewriter;              
        FicName = Name; // Nom du fichier courant pour suivi 
            }
```

Here in a context  i cross  with the listener. The Tokenstream is TOK visible by all the functions void

```
std::string retourchaine;
    std::vector<std::string> TAB{};
for (int i = ctx->start->getTokenIndex(); i <= ctx->stop>getTokenIndex(); i++)
    {
    TAB.push_back(TOK->get(i)->getText());   // HERE  TOK  
    }
    for (auto element : TAB)
    {
    if (element == "=") { element = ":="; }
    if (element != "As" && element != "Private" && element != "Public") 
    {
    std::cout << element << std::endl;
    retourchaine += element ;                // retour de la chaine au contexte 
    }
    }
    retourchaine = retourchaine + " ;";
    
    Rewriter->replace(ctx->start, ctx->stop, retourchaine );
  `
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i think that rewriting the token stream is not a good idea, because you can't
treat the general case of a tree. The TokenStreamRewriter tool of ANTLR is usefulness. If you use a listener , you can't change the AST tree and the contexts created by ANTLR. you must use a Bufferedwriter to do the job for rewriting the context you change locally in the final file of your translation.
Thanks to Ewa Hechsman and her program on github on a transpiler from Pascal to Python.
I think it'a real solution for a professional project.
So i agree with Ira Baxter. we need a rewriting tree